# Using (grep?) to determine which files haven't been downloaded

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

The summary of my problem is as follows:

I've got two text files (downloaded.txt and list.txt)

list.txt contains a list of URLs, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/file1.exe
http://example.com/file2.exe
http://example.com/file3.exe
http://example.com/file4.exe
http://example.com/file5.exe
```

downloaded.txt contains a list of files that have already been downloaded:

```
file1.exe
file2.exe
file3.exe
file5.exe
```

What I want to do is compare the two files so that I can see which files haven't been downloaded (in this example it would be `file4.exe`

How would I go about achieving this?

I tried doing this and let's just say the results were disastrous (10m+ 'results' and for some reason I had to keep pressing enter to get it to run. Also, there was only 144k lines):

```
while read url; do 
  if ! grep "$url" downloaded.txt; then 
    echo $url; 
fi; 
done < list.txt >> files_to_download.txt
```

Comment: is it always like downloaded.txt containing the last part of the urls in list.txt?

Comment: Downloaded.txt contains only the filenames. List.txt contains the full URLs with the filenames.

Comment: May I suspect that "you had to keep pressing enter to get it to run" has its reason in empty lines in list.txt that end up `if grep download.txt; then` reading from stdin and grepping "download.txt" and you might add `test  -z "$url" && continue` right in the line after the while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`  to compare the two files by using the last element in the URL:

```
$ awk -F/ 'FNR==NR {downloaded[$0]=$0; next} !($NF in downloaded)' downl list 
http://example.com/file4.exe
```

This loops the file `downloaded.txt` and stores its values in an array `downloaded[]`. Then, it loops through the file `list.txt` and checks if the last `/`-slice occurs in the array. If not, it prints the line.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` you can read the patterns from a file name (`-f` option). In your case, you can reverse the match (`-v`), assuming the filenames in `downloaded.txt` does not appear anywhere in the path:

```
grep -vFf downloaded.txt list.txt
```

`-F` does fixed string match.

this will give `http://example.com/file4.exe` as output. To get the file name:

```
grep -vFf downloaded.txt list.txt | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'
```

outputs `file4.exe`.

**Example:**

```
% cat list.txt 
http://example.com/file1.exe
http://example.com/file2.exe
http://example.com/file3.exe
http://example.com/file4.exe
http://example.com/file5.exe

% cat dl.txt 
file1.exe
file2.exe
file3.exe
file5.exe

% grep -vFf dl.txt list.txt                          
http://example.com/file4.exe

% grep -vFf dl.txt list.txt | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'
file4.exe
```

Comment: @Jake You can just do `grep -vFf downloaded.txt list.txt` if you want like i mention, you need the `awk` if you just need the filename

Comment: Yeah using `awk` alone seems to be the better option here since it's slightly faster than `grep`.